# ms sql query on count occurence of words in text column

Tags: sql-server-2008, text, count

I have a table called `webqueries` with a column named `qQuestion` of data type `text`(sql server 2008). I want to create a count on words used in `qQuestion` (excluding 'and', 'is' etc). My goal is to see how many times a person has asked a question about a specific product.

Comment: Could you please give an example, and sample output?

Comment: And in case you didn't know, the text datatype is being depreciated, please consider changing to varchar. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: 'SELECT TOP 2 [QueryID]  
      ,[qQuestion]  
  FROM [WEB_2011_DISCHEM2].[dbo].[WebQueries]  
  order by QueryID desc'  
  
QueryID  | qQuestion  

67745  | I would like to know the prices of Band-Aid I have to take 3 a day.  
67744  | Would you be be willing to sponsor us any samples of your Band-Aid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a table-valued function to parse words and join it to your query against qQuestion. In your schema, I recommend using `varchar(8000)` or `varchar(max)` instead of `text`. Meanwhile, the following should get you started:

```
create function [dbo].[fnParseWords](@str varchar(max), @delimiter varchar(30)='%[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]%')
returns @result table(word varchar(max))
begin
    if left(@delimiter,1)<>'%' set @delimiter='%'+@delimiter;
    if right(@delimiter,1)<>'%' set @delimiter+='%';
    set @str=rtrim(@str);
    declare @pi int=PATINDEX(@delimiter,@str);

    while @pi>0 begin
        insert into @result select LEFT(@str,@pi-1) where @pi>1;
        set @str=RIGHT(@str,len(@str)-@pi);
        set @pi=PATINDEX(@delimiter,@str);
    end

    insert into @result select @str where LEN(@str)>0;
    return;
end
go

select COUNT(*)
from webqueries q
cross apply dbo.fnParseWords(cast(q.qQuestion as varchar(max)),default) pw
where pw.word not in ('and','is','a','the'/* plus whatever else you need to exclude */)
```

Comment: **Thank you!!** I've just changed the select query to lookup the stopwords in a table and added pw.word in the SELECT  :          >    select COUNT(*) wordcount,pw.word
>    from [dbo].[WebQueries] q
>    cross apply dbo.fnParseWords(q.qQuestion ,default) pw
>    where  pw.word not in (select stopword from [dbo].[StopWords]) 
>    group by pw.word
>   order by wordcount desc